# Finding the proof of this logic problem.

Tags: logic, proof-writing

**Prove of disprove:**

**Premises:**

1) $J \lor (\lnot K \lor J)$

2) $K \lor (\lnot J \lor K)$

**Conclusion:**

$(J \land K) \lor (\lnot J \land \lnot K)$

**Proof:**

4)$ (J \lor J) \lor \lnot K$ [Commutation and association of 1)]

5) $J \lor \lnot K$ [Duplication of 4)]

6) $(K \lor K) \lor \lnot J$ [Commutation and association of 2)]

7) $K \lor \lnot J$ [Duplication of 6)]

8) $(J \lor \lnot K) \land (K \lor \lnot J)$ [Conjunction of 5) and 7)]

9) $[J \land (K \lor \lnot J)] \lor [\lnot K \land (K \lor \lnot J)]$ [Distribution of 8)]

10) $[(J \land K) \lor (J \land \lnot J)] \lor [\lnot K \land K] \lor (\lnot K \land \lnot J)] $Distribution of 9)

11) $[(J \land K) \lor (\lnot J \land \lnot K)] \lor [(J \land \lnot J) \lor (K \land \lnot K)]$
Association of 10)

12) As $[(J \land \lnot J) \lor (K \land \lnot K)]$ is always false, then by Disjunctive Syllogism:

$(J \land K) \lor (\lnot J \land \lnot K)$, as desired. Q.E.D

**I have two questions:**

1) Is everything correct?

2) Is there a shorter proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you did just fine, and your proof is absolutely correct.  And very well documented.

I think from $$[(J \land K) \lor (J \land \lnot J)] \lor [\lnot K \land K] \lor (\lnot K \land \lnot J)]\tag{10}$$
 you could simply state $$[(J\land K) \lor \underbrace{(F\lor F)}_{false} \lor (\lnot K \land \lnot J)]\tag{11}$$

And finally $$[(J\land K) \lor (\lnot J \land \lnot K)]\tag {12}$$

But I think, in the end, it simply comes down to how explicit one wants to be. For example, between my (11) and (12), In addition to disjunctive syllogism, I also used the commutative property of $\land$ when flipping from $\lnot K \land \lnot J$ to $\lnot J \land \lnot K$, just as you relied on commutativity between your $(10)$ and $(11)$.

**All in all, there's little to improve in your proof. The only thing to add, if you want to be completely explicit in terms of justification in your steps $(10)$ and $(11),$ add commutativity along with associativity of $(10).$**  Nice job.

Comment: Thank you for your brilliant ideas and encouraging words!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate approach: if 1) holds, you must have J true or not K or J true. So either J is true or K is false.

if 2) holds, by the same argument, K is true or J is false.

So if J is true, K is true which implies J and K true which implies the conclusion.

If J is false, then 1) implies K false. So not J and not K is true which implies the conclusion so done.

Comment: Thank you so much for your fast and interesting answer!

Comment: a word of warning: if you are studying a subject for an exam, rather than just learning maths, it is important to distinguish proofs that are a formal deduction within the system (such as yours), and arguments outside the system such as mine. Both are correct but be clear on which they want (probably yours).

Comment: Thank you for your wise comment!